# How can I choose to overwrite remote repository with local commits?

Tags: git, unfuddle

Basically, due to events beyond my control, my remote repo was moved - I did a lot of work on my local copy in the meantime and now I really just want to overwrite everything in the remote repo with my local files.

However, I don't seem to be able to do this. The closest I can get is to pull and merge, but then it wants to walk me through some convoluted process for merging. I don't want to merge. I want to overwrite. I don't need a new branch - basically, I just want a fresh start.

The remote repo is on unfuddle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Answer (score 65):

You can remove the branch and recreate it, let's say the branch that you want to overwrite is `dev`:

Remove the branch in your remote host(github)

```
git push origin :dev
```

Then just push your dev again:

```
git push origin dev
```

I use Github for hosting, not familiar with unfuddle, but I think it'll works for the unfuddle, too. :)

---

Just as @melee mentioned, you can also use

```
git push origin dev -f
```

<strike>(not sure whether the `-f` is valid, but `--force` is OK)</strike>

```
git push origin dev --force
```

to force overwrite the branch. I remember I did it before. Thanks @melee. :)

Comment: I think (and I'm not sure here) you could achieve the same result by doing `git push origin dev -f`

Comment: @melee yeah, it may not the only way to do so. I just like use `:` to remove the branch. :D

Comment: Thanks, guys. I had tried to use --force, but that didn't work. I had already figured out another way to achieve this by the time you wrote so didn't get to try your solution. Thank you, though.

Comment: In the end, I didn't solve this using git commands, per se. Instead, I just copied my local files to a temp directory, and then deleted my local files. then 'pull'ed down the out-dated files from the remote repo into the now-empty local folder. Then I copied over those out of date files from the temp directory, did a commit and then a push back to the repo.

That at least solved my immediate problem and now I am back on track with local and remote repo being in sync.

Comment: @ericgr you should add that as an answer!

Comment: ^ Except you lose all git history, which surely isn't ideal.

Comment: @Carson yeah, but that's what the OP want ;)

Comment: `-f` and `--force` are synonyms.

Comment: If I do this for the `master`branch (`git push origin master -f`), git does a `Writing objects`, then it seems all done, because a subsequent `git push origin master` just gives `Everything up-to-date`. I suppose it's fine then.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer right, it should be fine. However, personally, I don't suggest force updating master br, which suppose to be a stable branch. It's a good idea to use `git merge --squash` whenever merge new feature br to dev or master, so whenever sth happens unexpectedly, u can just revert that commit.

Answer (score 15):

Been having the same problem. This command worked for me.

```
git push --set-upstream origin master --force
```

Comment: Very Good solution, clean! BUT WARNING! DO IT ONLY ON SOLO, OR WITH AGREEMENTS OF WHOLE TEAM. Very very dangerous for a fully collaborative repos.

Answer (score 5):

How to do this for master branch, without pulling data down from the remote repo:

1. Create a new folder, init git, add remote repo - don't pull or fetch!

   `mkdir clean_repo`

   `git init`

   `git remote add origin <remote-repo>`
2. create (and switch to) empty local branch, add, commit and push a test file into this.

   `git checkout test`

   `echo "test" > test`

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "adding test"`

   `git push origin:test`
3. On github / bitbucket, change default branch to new branch
4. On local, switch to master branch, commit and push to remote repo / branch

   `git checkout -b master`

   `git push origin --mirror`

Answer (score 2):

Add remote repo if hadn't:

```bash
git remote add <remote-name> <remote-repo>

git push --set-upstream <remote-name> <branch-name> --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in github ecosystem, but why can't you just reset your remote repository url?

```
git remote set-url origin /path/to/your/new/remote/repository/url
```

You might also need to configure your up-stream branch by looking in [here](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/advanced-git-concepts-the-upstream-tracking-branch/).

for more on `git remote...`, please take a look [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).