# Git remote overwrite led to two disconnected histories

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to Git so I was playing around with it before I knew what workflow and structure I wanted to use for my development repository. I created a local repository that I wanted to use to replace a remote one. I am currently the only one using it (though I cloned on different machines).

Basically, I created a new local repository and got it the way I wanted it. I forced a push to the remote repository to overwrite the old one like stated here:
[How can I choose to overwrite remote repository with local commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386996/how-can-i-choose-to-overwrite-remote-repository-with-local-commits) ... well except that I used the URL instead of origin.

Then I added the remote repository and checked to see if it worked.

```
$ git remote add origin <url>
```

I looked at the full history and I ended up with something like this:

[image: gitk --all]

Oh no! So I removed the remote and no change. Now I have this detached history AND branches that don't exist. So then I tried this: [How do you remove an invalid remote branch reference from Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git)

It didn't help.

```
$ git remote show
```

Shows up empty. Is there any way to undo this? I don't see how just adding a remote could muck up my working directory this badly!

Edit: I just noticed that there is one branch on the old history that wasn't the same as a new one. Also, I did fetch after adding the remote repository. I can see the old branch in

```
$ git reflog --all
```

and it shows up as

```
16903f4 refs/remotes/origin/feature/test-feature@{0}: fetch origin: storing head
```

Comment: Which tree is the cleaned-up one that you want to keep? Did you draw these graphs manually? just asking as the 'remote/feature/test-feature' suggests as there was a remote called 'feature'..

Comment: Sorry, that should have been 'remote/origin/feature/test-feature'. The plots were drawn manually but both trees show up when I do `gitk --all`. I redrew the image so it looks a bit more like my situation. The top tree was the one I wanted to keep and the bottom one had the "old" repository history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the remote with the same name and deleting the remote branches that weren't similar. I think a better solution would be one without manually deleting branches (I already have the repository and history I want to use) but at least my problem is fixed!

1. If the remote repo was removed

   ```
   $ git remote add <same remote name> <url to the repo>
   ```
2. Remove old remote branches that aren't in the "new" repository

   ```
   $ git push <same remote name> --delete <branch name>
   ```

Comment: ok accept it as answered so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to merge the local history with the remote one, or simply keep one of them?

a) if you want to merge them, the 2 histories need to be connected first. Then `rebase` with `--root` is you friend I guess.

> --root Rebase all commits reachable from , instead of limiting them with an . This allows you to rebase the root commit(s)
>   on a branch. Must be used with --onto, and will skip changes already
>   contained in  (instead of ). When used together
>   with --preserve-merges, all root commits will be rewritten to have
>    as parent instead.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

b) if you want to keep, say, only the local changes and drop the remote ones: just delete the remote ref:

```
 git push origin :badbranch
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I'd say it's the latter. If I had access to the remote, I would delete the bare repository and push my local one; however, I don't have file access (only https). So I need to overwrite but I want to push the entire repository with all my branches. Some branches are the same name so I guess it tried to merge where it could and kept a detached history where it couldn't.